# How do you count the number of rows that meet a numerical condition in AWK?

Tags: awk

I have a 2 column text file that is sorted on column 2 (numbers, ascending) that I am trying to summarise by counting the number of lines that fall within a set region. This is set to 1000. In essence the text file will be read and if the number in column 2 lies between 0 and 1000 then in the output file there will be a new line that tallies this up, then the second line of the output file I will have the 1000-2000 region and so on until the end of the file is read.

Unfortunately the code I have been passed misses the first output line 0-1000 and doesn't output the maths correctly... I think it is ignoring the first line of the INPUT file? I don't know how easy it is to change or whether a more elegant way of writing it is available...

From my understanding the AWK command says

1. let x=0 and y=1000
2. if $2 >=0 && $2 < y, then +1 to x
3. print when y is reached
4. repeat for y+1000

but my first region of 1000 is missing

INPUT FILE: sorted & tab-delimited

```
aaaaa 675 
aaaaa 678
aaaaa 989
aaaaa 1001
aaaaa 1500
aaaaa 2020 
...
```

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{x=0;y=1000;}{
   if ($2 >= 0 && $2 < y) {x=x+1;}
   else {OFS="\t"; $2=y; $3=y+1000; $4=x; print$1,$2,$3,$4; x=0; y=y+1000}
   }' INput.txt > OUTput.txt
```

So, I was expecting:

```
aaaaa    0 1000 3
aaaaa 1000 2000 2
aaaaa 2000 3000 1
...
```

but what I am getting is

```
aaaaa 1000 2000 3
aaaaa 2000 3000 1
aaaaa 3000 4000 0 
...
```

which isn't correct given the input files.

(... denotes the rest of the file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [@JamesBrown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991690/10248678), here is a working edition:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
{ 
  while(c<$2) {
    if(c)
      print $1,c-1000,c,n
    n=0 
    c+=1000
  }
  n++
}
END {
  print $1,c-1000,c,n
}' file
```

Given your sample its output:

```
aaaaa   0       1000    3
aaaaa   1000    2000    2
aaaaa   2000    3000    1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192912/discussion-on-answer-by-oguz-ismail-how-do-you-count-the-number-of-rows-that-mee).

Answer (score 1):

Lets add some debug and see:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"                                                   # moved
    x=0
    y=1000
}
{
    printf "DEBUG NR=%d $2=%d y=%d\n",NR,$2,y > "/dev/stderr"  # added
    if ($2 >= 0 && $2 < y)
        x=x+1
    else {
        $2=y
        $3=y+1000
        $4=x
        print$1,$2,$3,$4
        x=0
        y=y+1000
    }
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk file
DEBUG NR=1 $2=675 y=1000
DEBUG NR=2 $2=678 y=1000
DEBUG NR=3 $2=989 y=1000
DEBUG NR=4 $2=1001 y=1000
aaaaa   1000    2000    3
DEBUG NR=5 $2=1500 y=2000  # if (1500 >= 0 && 1500 < 2000) {x=x+1} ie no print
DEBUG NR=6 $2=2020 y=2000
aaaaa   2000    3000    1
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk, most of the times, you can convert the `if` statement into a pattern, which make the script easier to understand at the same time more concise. My approach to this problem is in a script called *count.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    threshold = 1000
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

$2 > threshold {
    print first, threshold - 1000, threshold, count
    threshold += 1000
    count = 0
}

{
    first = $1
    count++
}

END {
    print first, threshold - 1000, threshold, count
}
```

## Notes

- The `BEGIN` pattern is easy: Here I declare the threshold and delimiters
- For those lines whose value in the second steps over the threshold (pattern: `$2 > threshold`), I print out the count so far for the previous lines, adjust the threshold, and reset the count
- For every line, I save the value of the first column, then count. It is important that this block is positioned **after** the `$2 > threshold` block or the count would be off by one
- At the end, I also print out the tally for the last batch

## Invoking the script

```
awk -f count.awk INput.txt > OUTput.txt
```